# Piezo connection causing RTC to go haywire

Tags: arduino-uno, rtc, piezo

When I connect a piezo (to pin 8), it causes the output of my RTC to go haywire and throw `165` errors into the results.

```
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2165/165/165 165:37:4 // Connected piezo
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2165/165/45 13:36:4
2165/165/165 25:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2165/165/45 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2165/165/45 13:36:4
2165/165/165 165:165:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2165/165/165 37:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2165/165/27 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2165/165/165 25:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2165/165/165 25:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2165/165/165 25:36:4
2165/165/165 25:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2016/3/25 13:36:4
2165/165/165 25:36:4
```

Here's my current layout...

[image: Photo of breadboard]

Worth noting:

- Disconnecting the piezo instantly solves the problem.
- Connecting to any other pins also caused the issue.

Here is the Fritzing diagram

[image: Fritzing diagram]

and schematic

[image: Schematic]

Here's the full code...

```c
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS1307 rtc;

#define PIN 6
#define TONE 8
const int buttonPin = 7;

long fadeTime = 1 * 60000L; // X minutes
int colorStops = 256;
int delaySpeed = fadeTime / colorStops;
int notes[] = {262,294,330,349};
int switchState = 1;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int timeHour = 13;
int timeMinute = 20;
uint32_t alarmLength = 5 * 60000L; // 5 minutes

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(4, PIN, NEO_RGB);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);

  if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    while (1);
  }
  if (! rtc.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
    // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__));
  }

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP); // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input

  strip.begin();
  strip.show();
}

void loop() {
  DateTime now = rtc.now(); 

  Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
  Serial.println();

  if (now.hour() == timeHour && now.minute() == timeMinute && now.second() == 00){
    // Fade in light
    for(int i = 1; i<colorStops; i++){
      if (kill() == true){ break; }

      for(int np = 0;np<strip.numPixels(); np++){
        strip.setPixelColor(np, strip.Color(i,i,0));
      }
      strip.show();
      delay(delaySpeed);
    }

    // Play tone after light fully bright
    for( uint32_t tStart = millis();  (millis()-tStart) < alarmLength; ){
      if (kill() == true){ break; }

      for(int np = 0;np<strip.numPixels(); np++){
        strip.setPixelColor(np, strip.Color(random(100,255),random(100,255),random(100,255)));
      }
      strip.show();

      tone(TONE, notes[random(0,3)]);
      delay(100);
    }

    noTone(TONE);

    for(int np = 0;np<strip.numPixels(); np++){
      strip.setPixelColor(np, strip.Color(0,0,0));
    }
    strip.show();
  }
}

bool kill() {
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == LOW) {
    noTone(TONE);

    for(int np = 0;np<strip.numPixels(); np++){
      strip.setPixelColor(np, strip.Color(0,0,0));
    }
    strip.show();
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a schematics diagram of your circuit, would make it easier to understand your connections as opposed to the picture. Could you also please attach your code

Comment: @evolutionizer Done.

Comment: Is it only in case of connection or also when you drive the piezo? Might it be because the piezo (and rtc) is drawing more current than the Arduino can supply?

Comment: @Paul I'm noticing only in the case of the connection, without trying to drive the piezo.

Comment: @Shpigford could you please add pinMode(TONE,OUTPUT); in setup and try again

Comment: @evolutionizer Boom! That did the trick. So, the follow up question being...why? :)

Comment: @Shpigford arduino by default sets pins to INPUT this could be causing things to screw up

Comment: I still don't get it (: but you might add it as an answer. So it can be accepted, this StackExchange  is still a little low on acceoted answers (:

Comment: @Shpigford Just an FYI the resistor connected to the LED is not doing anything, as both the legs are shorted

Comment: @Paul I am not very clear on why this issue either. I believe what is happening is that because the pin is set as INPUT by default there is not limiting in the amount of current this could lead to the m/c acting funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```c
pinMode(TONE,OUTPUT);
```

to `setup()` to fix the problem.